# Spring boot cache Hazelcast return empty list of cache names and no metrics will display

Tags: java, spring-boot, caching, hazelcast, metrics

I started to work with Hazelcast cache and I want to expose metrics for them and I don't know how to do it.

My java-config

`@Configuration
public class HazelcastConfiguration {

```
@Bean
public Config config(){
    return new Config()
            .setInstanceName("hazelcast-instace")
            .addMapConfig(
                    new MapConfig()
                    .setName("testing")
                    .setMaxSizeConfig(new MaxSizeConfig(10, MaxSizeConfig.MaxSizePolicy.FREE_HEAP_SIZE))
                    .setEvictionPolicy(EvictionPolicy.LRU)
                    .setTimeToLiveSeconds(1000)
                    .setStatisticsEnabled(true)
            );
}
```

}`

During startup application, I see only this logs

```
2019-11-30 19:56:01.579  INFO 13444 --- [           main] com.hazelcast.instance.AddressPicker     : [LOCAL] [dev] [3.12.4] Prefer IPv4 stack is true, prefer IPv6 addresses is false
2019-11-30 19:56:01.671  INFO 13444 --- [           main] com.hazelcast.instance.AddressPicker     : [LOCAL] [dev] [3.12.4] Picked [192.168.43.2]:5701, using socket ServerSocket[addr=/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0,localport=5701], bind any local is true
2019-11-30 19:56:01.694  INFO 13444 --- [           main] com.hazelcast.system                     : [192.168.43.2]:5701 [dev] [3.12.4] Hazelcast 3.12.4 (20191030 - eab1290) starting at [192.168.43.2]:5701
2019-11-30 19:56:01.695  INFO 13444 --- [           main] com.hazelcast.system                     : [192.168.43.2]:5701 [dev] [3.12.4] Copyright (c) 2008-2019, Hazelcast, Inc. All Rights Reserved.
2019-11-30 19:56:02.037  INFO 13444 --- [           main] c.h.s.i.o.impl.BackpressureRegulator     : [192.168.43.2]:5701 [dev] [3.12.4] Backpressure is disabled
2019-11-30 19:56:02.761  INFO 13444 --- [           main] com.hazelcast.instance.Node              : [192.168.43.2]:5701 [dev] [3.12.4] Creating MulticastJoiner
2019-11-30 19:56:02.998  INFO 13444 --- [           main] c.h.s.i.o.impl.OperationExecutorImpl     : [192.168.43.2]:5701 [dev] [3.12.4] Starting 4 partition threads and 3 generic threads (1 dedicated for priority tasks)
2019-11-30 19:56:02.999  INFO 13444 --- [           main] c.h.internal.diagnostics.Diagnostics     : [192.168.43.2]:5701 [dev] [3.12.4] Diagnostics disabled. To enable add -Dhazelcast.diagnostics.enabled=true to the JVM arguments.
2019-11-30 19:56:03.007  INFO 13444 --- [           main] com.hazelcast.core.LifecycleService      : [192.168.43.2]:5701 [dev] [3.12.4] [192.168.43.2]:5701 is STARTING
2019-11-30 19:56:05.085  INFO 13444 --- [           main] c.h.internal.cluster.ClusterService      : [192.168.43.2]:5701 [dev] [3.12.4] 

Members {size:1, ver:1} [
    Member [192.168.43.2]:5701 - 6ed511ff-b20b-4875-9b39-2dc734d4a9aa this
]

2019-11-30 19:56:05.142  INFO 13444 --- [           main] com.hazelcast.core.LifecycleService      : [192.168.43.2]:5701 [dev] [3.12.4] [192.168.43.2]:5701 is STARTED
2019-11-30 19:56:05.295  INFO 13444 --- [e.HealthMonitor] c.h.internal.diagnostics.HealthMonitor   : [192.168.43.2]:5701 [dev] [3.12.4] processors=4, physical.memory.total=23,9G, physical.memory.free=11,8G, swap.space.total=27,2G, swap.space.free=10,3G, heap.memory.used=306,9M, heap.memory.free=357,1M, heap.memory.total=664,0M, heap.memory.max=5,3G, heap.memory.used/total=46,23%, heap.memory.used/max=5,63%, minor.gc.count=0, minor.gc.time=0ms, major.gc.count=0, major.gc.time=0ms, load.process=100,00%, load.system=100,00%, load.systemAverage=n/a thread.count=37, thread.peakCount=37, cluster.timeDiff=0, event.q.size=0, executor.q.async.size=0, executor.q.client.size=0, executor.q.client.query.size=0, executor.q.client.blocking.size=0, executor.q.query.size=0, executor.q.scheduled.size=0, executor.q.io.size=0, executor.q.system.size=0, executor.q.operations.size=0, executor.q.priorityOperation.size=0, operations.completed.count=1, executor.q.mapLoad.size=0, executor.q.mapLoadAllKeys.size=0, executor.q.cluster.size=0, executor.q.response.size=0, operations.running.count=0, operations.pending.invocations.percentage=0,00%, operations.pending.invocations.count=0, proxy.count=0, clientEndpoint.count=0, connection.active.count=0, client.connection.count=0, connection.count=0
```

after autowired class CacheManager I and run on it function getCacheNames I see an empty list, and I don't know why?

and during first added to the cache in the log display

```
2019-11-30 20:11:12.760  INFO 16464 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] c.h.i.p.impl.PartitionStateManager       : [192.168.43.2]:5701 [dev] [3.12.4] Initializing cluster partition table arrangement...
```

In Metrics Config file I have this and nothing in metrics will diplay:

```
    @Autowired
private CacheMetricsRegistrar cacheMetricsRegistrar;
```

anyone have ide why its doesn't work?

Answer (score 1):

The cache is initialized when you insert the first entry into it. That is why you don't see any cache in `CacheManager` at the beginning. After you insert the first value you should see `HazelcastCache` in `cacheManager.caches`.

The same with `CacheMetricsRegistrar`, I just tried and see `HazelcastCacheMeterBinderProvider` in `binderProviders`.

Answer (score 0):

For Spring Boot 2.x create your registration component:

```
@Component
@AllArgsConstructor
public class CacheMetricsRegistrator {

  private final CacheMetricsRegistrar cacheMetricsRegistrar;
  private final CacheManager cacheManager;
  private final Config cacheConfig;
    
  @PostConstruct
  public void register() {
    this.cacheConfig.getMapConfigs().keySet().forEach(
        cacheName -> this.cacheMetricsRegistrar.bindCacheToRegistry(
           this.cacheManager.getCache(cacheName))
    );
  } 
}
```

for your cache configuration of Hazelcast:

```
@EnableCaching
@Configuration
public class HazelcastConfig {

    private MapConfig mapPortfolioCache() {
        return new MapConfig()
            .setName("my-entity-cache")
            .setEvictionConfig(new EvictionConfig().setMaxSizePolicy(MaxSizePolicy.FREE_HEAP_SIZE).setSize(200))
            .setTimeToLiveSeconds(60*15);
    }

    @Bean
    public Config hazelCastConfig() {
    
      Config config = new Config()
        .setInstanceName("my-application-hazelcast")
        .setNetworkConfig(new NetworkConfig().setJoin(new JoinConfig().setMulticastConfig(new MulticastConfig().setEnabled(false))))
        .addMapConfig(mapPortfolioCache());
    
      SubZero.useAsGlobalSerializer(config);
      return config;        
    }   
}
```